# WDS&PXE booting using Grub2 - choosing menuentry

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, grub2

I have problem with booting to WDS using PXE with Grub2. Actually we are using WDS with DHCP (Windows) - on DHCP I have WDS IP and 'grldr' file as bootfile name (grub loader) with menu.lst file (on target computer). I booting via pxe, grub searching menu.lst on hdd, loading menu.lst - I can choose WDS or HDD.

Today, I must enable WDS on EFI platform (grldr doesn't run on EFI platform). I installed another WDS, configured DHCP for one test platform and added grub2 file as "Bootfile Name" - and there is a problem. Machine booting to grub2 commandline..How can I add menuentry with WDS and HDD? I can boot WDS manually from command line but, where should I put grub.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

On a PXE scenario grub2 will look for its configuration file depending on how its image was created. please look here for an example.

https://github.com/openSUSE/kiwi/wiki/Setup-PXE-boot-with-EFI-Using-GRUB2